# Java : Crash without exception

Tags: java, debugging, exception, concurrenthashmap

I'm trying to debug some code that look like this :

```java
class MyClass {
    public void myMethod(HashMap<String, String> inputMap) {
        try {
            ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> cm = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
            cm.putAll(inputMap);
            
            try {
                for (Object key : cm.keySet()) {
                    cm.put(key.toString(), "");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            System.out.println("After try catch");            

        } finally {
            System.out.println("In finally");
        }
    }
}
```

By using the debugger in InteliJ I've figured out that this piece of code have an issue on the `for` loop line.

- The execution pass from the for loop to the `finally` clause without passing in the `catch` clause neither the code after the `try/catch`.
- The `cm` object isn't empty (there is around 30 elements in it).
- I'm using java 7, `System.getProperty("java.version")` give `1.7.0_85`
- When I try to call the `cm.keySet()` mnually from the InteliJ debugger I have the following error message `No such instance method: 'keySet'`. But when I look at the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#keySet()) of the ConcurentHashMap class this method should exists.
- When I run `cm.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()` I see the method `public java.util.Set java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.keySet()` in the methods list.
- This code is not running on the main thread.
- This don't display any error message in the console and I'm not able to catch an exception.

Does anyone have an idea of what could be the problem there? I've tried everything I could think of, and I'm out of options.

**Edit problem fixed**
The issue wasn't even in the code itself, it was that the compiler was updated from java 7 to java 8 without me noticing and without crashing during the compilation, while the java version that I use on my server was java 7. Since I didn't have the possibility to change neither the compiler version neither the version on the server, I've rewritten the code in another way so that it will work on both version.
It gives something like this :

```java
class MyClass {
    public void myMethod(HashMap<String, String> inputMap) {
        try {
            ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> cm = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
            cm.putAll(inputMap);
            
            try {
                Enumeration<String> keys = cm.keys();
                while(keys.hasMoreElements()) {
                    String key = keys.nextElement();
                    cm.put(key, "");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            System.out.println("After try catch");            

        } finally {
            System.out.println("In finally");
        }
    }
}
```

Ps: Thank you, @cyberbrain, I wouldn't have figured this out without your advice on catching Throwable rather than Exception.

Comment: maybe you get an error - try to catch a `Throwable` instead of an exception. I would guess(!) that you have a problem when you loop through the keyset of the map and at the same time try to manipulate the very same map.

Comment: I'll try that I didn't think of the Throwable.

Comment: runs fine here with JDK 1.7.0_80.

Comment: `This don't display any error message`, that is hardly impossible. The JVM always prints some error, if there is an error. Probably you are debugging code that is not in sync with the code in your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `Object` with `String`

```java
class MyClass {
    public void myMethod(HashMap<String, String> inputMap) {
        try {
            ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> cm = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(inputMap);

            try {
                for (String key : cm.keySet()) {
                    cm.put(key, "");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            System.out.println("After try catch");

        } finally {
            System.out.println("In finally");
        }
    }
}
```

You can also replace the entire for loop with the following:

```java
cm.replaceAll((k, v) -> "");
```

edit: Realized lamdas wont work on JDK 1.7

Comment: No lambdas in JDK 1.7

Comment: Good catch, forgot about that!

Comment: I've corrected this, but this wasn't the issue